# Explode in php for DataBase

Tags: php

It's not working when I get the value from a url like `selected.php?aa=2,3,`

```
$mainclass  = $_GET['aa'];
$classarray = explode(",", $mainclass);
$classarray = array_walk($classarray, 'intval');
$classa     = implode(',', $classarray);

$makefeed = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM studentnew WHERE fieldname IN (".$classa.")"); while ($cc = mysql_fetch_array($makefeed))  { }
```

Comment: What's the error/what's your result/what's is not working?

Comment: `intval` does not change the values of the array and `array_walk` returns a boolean value, not an array. See the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php You are looking for `array_map`.

Comment: Please explain your needs.....?

Answer (score 1):

When using [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php), the key/index is passed to the callback function (`intval()`) as the second argument.

[`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)'s second argument is the radix. You would not want the array index being passed in as the radix. This will return incorrect results (I assume you want them all as decimal).

Instead, use [`array_map()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Also, `array_walk()` works by reference and returns a Boolean. So you are assigning this Boolean to the `$classarray` variable.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$classarray = array_walk($classarray, 'intval');
```

to

```
array_walk($classarray, 'intval');
```

array_walk return boolean, not array.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: This won't work. If you want to change the value, you have to define the parameter as a reference and I don't think `intval` is doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You need [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

Change

```
$classarray = array_walk($classarray, 'intval');
```

to

```
$classarray = array_map('intval' ,$classarray);
```